# How to fix DNS leak OpenVPN on Ubuntu 20.04?

Tags: networking, dns, vpn, openvpn

Okay, so basically I am using openvpn to connect on one of the NordVPN's servers.
But long story short, I haven't even noticed all until this night, my DNS is leaking somehow.

My sys. info:

```
str1ng@str1ng:~$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS
Release:    20.04
Codename:   focal
```

Went to the NordVPN's support, been there for like 2 hours, couldn't solve it, so it happens to be that this is my only hope at the moment.

I've tried so many things... Like answer from here: https://www.ubuntubuzz.com/2015/09/how-to-fix-openvpn-dns-leak-in-linux.html

Also I've tried editing .ovpn server config file with adding `block-outside-dns` , but then I am getting this:

```
Options error: Unrecognized option or missing or extra parameter(s) in /etc/openvpn/ovpn_tcp/ch303.nordvpn.com.tcp.ovpn:18: block-outside-dns (2.4.7)
Use --help for more information.
```

So that doesn't make things any better, so after that, I've done:

```
pull-filter ignore "block-outside-dns"
```

And then ran `sudo openvpn /etc/.....` to connect to server, but also nothing, my DNS's still leaking.

Apart from that they told me to disable IPv6, so I did that by following this guide:

> Open a terminal window. Type this command:
>
> sudo nano /etc/sysctl.conf   Add the following at the bottom of the
> file:
>
> net.ipv6.conf.all.disable_ipv6 = 1 net.ipv6.conf.default.disable_ipv6
> = 1 net.ipv6.conf.lo.disable_ipv6 = 1 net.ipv6.conf.tun0.disable_ipv6 = 1
> Save and close the file. Reboot the device. To re-enable IPv6, remove the above lines from /etc/sysctl.conf and reboot the device.

Also, I've done this:
https://support.nordvpn.com/Connectivity/Linux/1134945702/Change-your-DNS-servers-on-Linux.htm

But after doing this and checking on resolv.conf ; it's again overwritten by NetworkManager.

This looks like infinite loop. If anyone can help I'd be grateful

Edited with what one of users have required

```
 str1ng@str1ng:~/Desktop$ ls -al /etc/resolv.conf
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 39 Jun  8 16:13 /etc/resolv.conf -> ../run/systemd/resolve/stub-resolv.conf


dpkg -l *dnsmasq*
Desired=Unknown/Install/Remove/Purge/Hold
| Status=Not/Inst/Conf-files/Unpacked/halF-conf/Half-inst/trig-aWait/Trig-pend
|/ Err?=(none)/Reinst-required (Status,Err: uppercase=bad)
||/ Name             Version           Architecture Description
+++-================-=================-============-============================================
un  dnsmasq          <none>            <none>       (no description available)
ii  dnsmasq-base     2.80-1.1ubuntu1.4 amd64        Small caching DNS proxy and DHCP/TFTP server
un  dnsmasq-base-lua <none>            <none>       (no description available)



str1ng@str1ng:~/Desktop$ grep -i dns /etc/systemd/resolved.conf
#DNS=
#FallbackDNS=
#MulticastDNS=no
#DNSSEC=no
#DNSOverTLS=no
#DNSStubListener=yes
```

Comment: How do you know that your DNS is leaking? Edit your question and show me a screenshot of the dns leak test results from https://dnsleaktest.com standard test. Also show me `ls -al /etc/resolv.conf` and `cat /etc/resolv.conf` and `dpkg -l *dnsmasq*` and `grep -i dns /etc/systemd/resolved.conf`.

Comment: related: [update-systemd-resolved](https://github.com/jonathanio/update-systemd-resolved)

Comment: @heynnema for some reason today when I tried to turn on computer, it just showed me "0.133081 DMAR: Firmware bug..." Currently, I am booted from USB, and can't even install new system again, because it has some sort of bug, so I am currently dealing with that.
Anyways, the way I knew that my DNS is leaking was exactly by the tests from dnsleaktest.com and exactly the extended one. I am trying to install system again on this pc, so after I am done with that, I'll hopefully be able to update you with ls -al /etc/resolv.conf  and with other stuff too...

Comment: Don't reinstall. See if you can boot into maintenance mode.

Comment: @heynnema I wasn't able to do so... Unfortunately...
Btw. I've updated question with what you required

Comment: Are you able to boot now? You're running on a new install of Ubuntu, yes? Are you still getting the DMAR error? Show me the screenshot of the standard DNS leak test, and `cat /etc/resolv.conf`.

Comment: Sorry for late respons. Anyways, after I rebooted and installed NordVPN over again, I was able to fix the problem that caused me problems with connecting with `nordvpn connect` command, but right now I am able to connect with `nordvpn connect` command, and now I don't have DNS leaks (because I don't use openvpn anymore).

I am sorry once again and thank you!